# Why is dataclass is not working correctly?

Tags: python, module, python-dataclasses

The dataclass-function is not working. For example,

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

p = Person("Jonas", 27)
print(p)
```

The error message occurs when I try to define p:

```
TypeError: Person() takes no arguments
```

Hence, dataclass is not handling the `__init__` function appropriately.
The dataclasses.py file is in
 `C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\Tut_Dataclass\test_env\Lib\site-packages` (1),
where I also find a folder `dataclasses-0.6.dist-info`.
Typing `where python` in comand prompt (in VSCode) gives the correct location  `C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\Tut_Dataclass\test_env\Scripts\python.exe`.
Checking `sys.path`shows that (1) is listed and therefore python should find the module dataclasses.
I checked numpy (installed via pip) and it works properly.
As a novice in VSCode and python, I appreciate any idea to solve this issue.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure you are using python3.7+?

Comment: I get output: `Person(name='Jonas', age=27)`

Comment: I am using python 3.9.4

Comment: I finally reinstalled python and VSCode - its working now. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 4):

If restarting / reinstalling didn't work, the problem might be in the order of decorators. e.g:

```
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
```

works. While:

```
@dataclass
@dataclass_json
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
```

throws `TypeError: Person() takes no arguments`

Comment: The OP didn't mention anything about a 3rd party library such as `dataclass_json`, so this answer is quite confusing.

Comment: If it's technically irrelevant but practically exactly what you needed to see, does it get an updoot?  I think so.